# Android Login Activity with automatic retrieving of the password in sharedpreferences/SQLite

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I was working on an android app and trying to create a login activity and I asked myself one thing. Of course it is possible create a login activity with the possibility of storing the username/password with all the security problems concerned, but is it possible create an activity in which a user can put his login name and automatically the app retrieves the password? It would be great!

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.  What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

well, Macho its not good stuff because anyone can sniff your username since it is not type of password. But as you ask, it can be possible as user enters username and unfoccussed the edittext you can fetch password from sharedpreferences or may be from sqlite database and show in password edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You should be aware however that if the phone is lost or stolen, the new "owner" of that phone could be automatically logged on.